# Recover DB2 table after CLI load mode on is set

Tags: db2

I need to load large amount of data on a table in DB2 database. I am using CLI load mode on a table written in C using SQLSetStmtAttr function. Select statements does not work (the table gets locked) when it is set.

When the loading of the data completes I am doing load mode off. After that the table becomes  accessible so that i can perform select from db2 command line tools (or control center).

But the problem is when my C program crashes or fails before doing load mode off. The table is always locked. I have to drop the table and all previous data is lost.

My question is whether there is a way to recover the table?

Comment: It would *probably* be useful if you provide the *actual error message* you get when trying to access the table after a failed load.  For example, `SQL0668N reason code 3`.

Comment: I am getting the same error which you have mentioned `SQL0668N Operation not allowed for reason code 3` . The table is in the Load Pending state. A previous LOAD attempt on this table resulted in failure. No access to the table is allowed until the LOAD operation is restarted or terminated. So how can I terminate it if the C code which opened the connection and set the load mode on crashed.

Answer (score 0):

DBMS Documentation is your friend.  You can [read the description](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00668n.html) of `SQL0668N` (or any other error!) to find out what reason code 3 means, as well as how to fix it.

Basically, when a LOAD operation fails, you need to perform some cleanup on the table – either `restart` or `terminate` it.  This can be done using the LOAD utility from outside of your program (e.g., `LOAD from /dev/null of del TERMINATE into yourtable` nonrecoverable) but you can also do it programatically.

Typically you would do this using the [`db2Load()` API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.api.doc/doc/r0008704.html), and setting the `piLongActionString` member of the `db2LoadStruct` parameter you pass to `db2Load()`, with the same RESTART or TERMINATE operation.

It looks like you can set the `SQL_ATTR_LOAD_INFO` statement to the same `db2LoadStruct` when using a CLI Load, too, but I am not sure if this would actually work to complete a load restart / terminate.